# When is the header called while in the function of a class

Tags: php

I know that when I have php code that connects to database:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);  
if($conn->connect_errno==0)
{
  ...
  header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
$conn->close();
```

Jump to index will be called after all other things are done, so connection will be closed first.

But what if I would I would make a class that manages database operations?
for example when I have:

```
$db->connect(); //connects to db
$db->dosomething(); //this function have header('Location: index.php') in it
$db->close();
```

Would jump to index.php be called at the end of dosomething() function or after page that called that function is loaded and all php operations are complete?

Comment: If you want to redirect, the standard practice is to add `exit();` immediately after a `Location` header. In this case, the script exits immediately and no other code is executed. If there is no `exit()` then subsequent code may be executed.

Comment: Copy paste the code from the method instead of calling it, and you'll find the answer

Comment: @DarraghEnright subsequent code Will be executed unless an `exit` is a used

Comment: Sorry, absolutely - will, not may.

Answer (score 0):

The [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function doesn't actually "jump" to another page, it simply sets a value that will be a part of the server's response. It can also be used to change the HTTP code (like issuing a 404), or the content-type (for downloading a file).

It might be helpful to think of your PHP code as if it was generating a "document" that it will send back to the web browser. That document starts with a 'Header', and then typically contains a 'Body' (where the HTML and scripts will go).

When you call:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

That just sets that value in your response "document's" Header.

The Header and Body responses are sent effectively at the same time: when the PHP thread finishes. That's either when *all* your code has been executed, or you've explicitly stopped the thread with `exit();`.

In other words, **your code won't "jump" or stop at the `header` line**, it will continue on and execute any remaining lines of code.